# Get decimals & absolutes from a array in java script

Tags: javascript

This is an `array = ["1.40954", "101", "5.1028", "2000", "70.38"]`. What can I do to get these array into two array like, `decimal = ["1.40954", "5.1028", "70.38"]` and `absolute = [101, 2000]` in javascript?

Comment: Write some code, and if you get stuck, then ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo operator `%`.

It works for numbers or strings or both together mixed.

```js
let arr = [1.40954, "101", "5.1028", "2000", "70.38"];

let dec = arr.filter(el => el % 1 !== 0);
let abs = arr.filter(el => el % 1 === 0);

console.log(dec);
console.log(abs);
```

Comment: Great Code....but they all are string

Comment: @mogoja doesnt matter works too

Comment: Thats right it works so well.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are storing the values as strings, you can just use indexOf to check if the values contain .

```
var array = ["1.40954", "101", "5.1028", "2000","70.38"]
var decimal = [], absolute = [];
array.forEach(function(val){
    if(val.indexOf(".") > -1){decimal.push(val);}
    else{absolute.push(val);}
});
console.log(decimal, absolute);
```

Comment: It worked indeed lengthy

Comment: Complaining of "lengthy" when you show no code @mogoja, i have no word to describe

Comment: I agree with you. Your code is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
    array  = ["1.40954", "101", "5.1028", "2000", "70.38"] ;
    absolute   =  [];
    decimal  = [];
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ( Number.isInteger( Number(array[i]) ))
            absolute.push(array [i])
        else
            decimal.push(array [i])
    }

    console.log( absolute , decimal);
```

Comment: Thats elegant coding